# SoundPool sometimes doesn't play sounds (I have multiple sounds firing simultaneously)

Tags: android, soundpool

For my Android app I show a bunch of buttons and for each I create a 'pop' sound after a short 'scale' animation.  It could be that there are up to 20 buttons at a time, and they scale in to view randomly within a 1 second period.

This works fine to start, but after a while the sound doesn't play anymore, and indeed, some other of the sounds in the SoundPool no longer play either...

My Activity:

```
protected SoundPool soundPool;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.soundPool = new SoundPool(100, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    this.popAId = this.soundPool.load(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pop_a, 1);
    ...
    FlowLayout answersLayout = (FlowLayout) findViewById(R.id.answerbuttons_layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
        addAnswerButton(savedInstanceState, answersLayout, answers.get(i));
    }
    ...
}

protected Button addAnswerButton(Bundle savedInstanceState, FlowLayout answersLayout, String text) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(text);
    answersLayout.addView(b);
    class myRunnable implements Runnable {
        protected Button b = null;

        public myRunnable(Button b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            scaleView(this.b, 0, 1);
        }
    }
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new myRunnable(b), (long) (Math.random() * 1000));
    }
    return b;
}

public void scaleView(View v, float startScale, float endScale) {
    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
    anim.setDuration(250);
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    class myAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        protected View v = null;
        public myAnimationListener(View v) { this.v = v; }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Play pop sound
            Log.i("Hello", "World");
            Log.i("GameActivity::scaleView", String.format("%1$d", soundPool.play(popAId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    }
    anim.setAnimationListener(new myAnimationListener(v));
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: Might be a little late, but if anyone else has the same question, you can fix it by increasing the number of max sound streams by doing `setMaxStreams(x)` where x is the max number of simultaneous sounds.